# How to assign incremental numbers but only if another column is different value

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am trying to assign a unique ID to companies that I have a list of. These companies have multiple products so the company name appears on multiple rows.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($B2<>"",IF((COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,$B2)>0),INDEX($A$1:$R2,MATCH($B2,$B$1:$B1,0),12),CONCATENATE("C00",ROW($C2))),""))
```

The above kind of works but it will assign C001 then it will see that Column C row value matches and skips but it ten assigns C009 if the next company name is 8 rows down rather than assigning C002 to this next company.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($B2<>"",IF((COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,$B2)>0),INDEX($A$1:$R2,MATCH($B2,$B$1:$B1,0),12),CONCATENATE("RET00",ROW($B2))),""))
```

I expect each different company name to have an incremental unique ID inputted to Company ID column rows.

Here is my data and expected result:

[image: Sheet Example]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Now done thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B, 
  {UNIQUE(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)), 
 TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTUNIQUE(B2:B))), "C0#")}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]